# What does it mean, "surf the echelons "?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Fletcher says to Ray about Michael Pearson:

> He's clear and objective about ambition  and he can **surf the echelons**
>   of our complicated culture.  He knew how to take advantage of his
>   advantage.

What does it mean, "surf the echelons "?

I find this line in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Comment: Echelons are levels of power or authority; to surf is to navigate easily and confidently.

Comment: how can one surf levels of power or authority?

Comment: "Work and communicate effectively and confidently with colleagues and stakeholders at all levels of seniority", it says in my job description.

Comment: Don't kiss ass to the boss, and don't feed bullshit to the guys in the mail room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most of your recent questions, this is a metaphor, but not a standard one. It isn't a fixed idiom, but something that the speaker has created.

To "surf" means to move easily and confidently. *(thanks Michael)*

> Surf the internet.

"Echelons" are ranks, with the higher ranks having fewer people than the lower ranks (forming a metaphorical triangle)

> The regiment marched in echelon formation.
>
> (I've just been writing a text on echelon matrices)

So "move easily and confidently between working with high ranking people and low ranking people".